# Mulitple divs/same class with different css

Tags: jquery, css

I need to change the style of a div that has the same class as other divs. The site is built with Umbraco and I don't have access to the HTML to add an id to the div I am trying to change. The structure of the HTML looks like this

```
<header>...</header>
<div class="container">...</div>
<div class="container">...</div>
<div class="container">...</div>
```

I need to add a background image to the 3rd div. I am not exactly sure of the proper way to do this rather it can be done with CSS or if it's best to use JavaScript. I tried using jQuery to select the div by its index but I wasn't getting anywhere with that. This is what I started with.

```
<script>
$( ".container:eq( 2 )" ).css( "background", "url(/media/9165540/happy-female.jpg)" );
</script>
```

I also need to add

```
background-size: cover;
```

but I wasn't sure how to add that as well. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Research CSS pseudo classes `:nth-child`, `:nth-of-type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the input. My solution is

```
$( "body" ).find( ".container" ).eq( 3 ).addClass( "background-image" );
```

Answer (score 2):

in jQuery you can use:

```
$('.container').eq(2).css({'background':'url(/media/9165540/happy-female.jpg)', 'background-size': 'cover'});
```

or add specyfic class to all '.container's by using:

```
$('.container').each(function(i){ $(this).addClass('container-'+i); });
```

and styling it by class.
Or at least you can use CSS:

```
.container:nth-child(2)
```

but this is very problematic solution... Because CSS don't change third container always, but change container if it is in third position of it's parent. For example if you have something like this:

```
<div>
<header>...</header>
<footer>...</footer>
<div class="container">...</div>
<div class="container">...</div>
</div>
```

and want to select the second container you must do:

```
.container:nth-child(4)
```

because the second container is in fourth position relative to the  parent.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not worried about IE8 then the [:nth-of-type pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) may be the way to go

```html
<div class="container">...</div>
<div class="container">...</div>
<div class="container">...</div>
```

```css
.container {
    width: 300px; 
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
.container:nth-of-type(3) {
    border-color: red;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rpv69x4y/

This option is a little more flexible than `:nth-child` as you could have markup like the following and it would still select the **third element with a class of `.container`**.

```html
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<div class="container">...</div>
<p class="container">...</p>
<div class="container">...</div><!-- I get selected -->
```

Answer (score 0):

See: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp

```
.container:nth-of-type(2)
```

Should do the trick although this is a less than ideal solution, you really need something to scope it to. Other wise any page with 2x container elements will inherit the style.